# Double theme name in media path in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

I am sure this is a fault on my side but I would like to see if anyone have any idea how to find the error.

I am using my own theme, based on some other theme.

When I upload files in the **media manager** in october cms it seem to be working just fine but when I try to get the path, example:

```
<img src="{{ 'myimg.png' | media }}"/>
```

it returns the path:

> http://my.domain.com/theme-name/theme-name/storage/app/media/myimg.png

When the file is actually located at:

> http://my.domain.com/theme-name/storage/app/media/myimg.png

it looks to me like the theme-name is inserted twice, but I can't seem to find anything wrong in the configurations or anything.

So hopefully that is enough information to work with, I will be happy to fill in any missing information but I don't know what more is needed.

Comment: when you upload image from OctoberCMS Backend Media Manager then your image must have been saved at <your_domain_name>/storage/app/media folder

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder if it might be giving me problems because my OctoberCMS is not in the root but in a sub folder. something like: 'http://my.domain.com/october/' I will have to look deeper into it and better understand what is actually going wrong.

Comment: What build are you using? There was an issue in 446 and a couple below that affected media path generation, 447 should fix it though.

Comment: Thanks @LukeTowers that explains a lot since it just so happen to be the build I am using, I will try to upgrade and see but if that was a known issue I am pretty sure that is what I have been experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a **bug**, and **from version 447 it is fixed** (I have tried and **verified** that is the case). Thanks to @LukeTowers for pointing it out!

On builds before 447, the way I found to solve it, was to change in 'webroot/october/config/cms/cms.php' from relative to absolute path, since it is on the server where it will be running that kind of works, and I still **have no clue why the relative doesn't work for the case mentioned** under storage:

```
'storage' => [
    'media' => [
        'folder' => 'media',
        //'path'   => '/storage/app/media',
        'path'  => 'https://my.domain.com/october/storage/app/media/',
         ...
```

Just wanted to leave it for completeness so that anyone else having the problem might either be helped or even explain the parts I can't.

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

after seeing your code. I don't think there is any problem but now you need to create a sub-domain and move octobercms there and it will work !!!

Thanks

Comment: I have the installation here https://qrikko.com/youmatter but the things I upload in the back end is looking in: 'https://qrikko.com/youmatter/youmatter/storage/...' if I click the url-link in the media manager or try to access it with {{image.png | media}}. So the path should contain one youmatter not two.

Comment: I also have a problem where images don't work in a richeditor field in a repeatable (setup in theme yaml) but didn't mention it as I figure that can be unrelated.